# Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem Applied

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

"The group S6 acts on the group Z6 via σ([a]) = [σ(a)], for σ ∈ S6 and a∈{1,...,6}.

A permutation that is also an isomorphism is called an automorphism. The set G of
automorphisms of Z6 is a group. Use the orbit-stabiliser theorem to find its order."

I am considering the element [1], and I have found that the size of its orbit is 2 (as isomorphisms preserve orders of elements, [1] may only be mapped to itself or [5]). However, I have no idea how to go about finding the size of the stabiliser of [1]. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that for any homomorphism $\pi$, the value of $\pi(g)$ determines the value of $\pi$ on all of $\langle g \rangle$. What does that mean in your situation?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. So does this look like a correct explanation?

"For some isomorphism pi, we have pi([k])=k*pi([1]).

If this isomorphism is in the stabiliser of [1], then we must have pi([1])=[1], so it follows that pi([k])=[k] for all k∈{1,...,6}.

Hence the only isomorphism in the stabiliser of [1] is the trivial permutation, which leaves every element unchanged."

Comment: @gillington: looks good to me :)